# Implementing scroll in a DIV

Tags: javascript, ajax, infinite-scroll

I have this Javascript code below. This helps me to gain infinite scroll in a webpage. What if i want to implement that infinite scroll in a DIV. How can i modify this code to use it inside a DIV? 
can anyone please help me. *Say the id of my DIV is #wrapper in which the scroll content is to be displayed*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
                    success: function(html){
                        if(html){
                            $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                        }else{
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace mentions of `window` with your chosen div.

Also, compare `scrollTop()` with `scrollHeight`, rather than fashioning the height which may or may not be accurate, and use `>=` to be on the safe side - not all browsers behave themselves.

Comment: replacing like as  if($(window).scrollHeight() >= $(document).height() - $(wrapper).height()){  or what?